# Android - Migrate data from Realm to Room

Tags: android, realm, android-room

Actually I've an app with some local data, and I used Realm to store them. Today I would like to update it, and switch to Room.

The thing is that some user already have data stored with Realm, and for now, my app only store the data locally, there is no cloud of something. This means that if I just switch from Realm to Room, some existing user will lost their data. 
I made some search, and I thought about, when the user will open the app, make a query of all the Realm data, and switch them to Room, keep it for few weeks, and then delete Realm.

The thing is that I made a test project to see if it's functional, but I noticed that I will have to create the model twice (the existing one with Realm and the new one with Room).

Does someone have a better idea or way to do it, or it's my only way to go ?

Comment: I don't see any other option to migrate data from your user's device realm database to room :/

Comment: How did you solve this ?

Comment: @Ran I finally did what I said in the post, in the new version of my app, put a migration process at the opening, leave it like this for a month or two, the time that everybody do the migration and finally removed realm.