# Replace Realm DB in the an existing Android app with Room DB

Tags: android, realm, android-room, realm-mobile-platform

We have a 4+ year android application that relies on the Realm DB. We are exploring the possibility to adopt the Room Database going forward. There are a few challenges and queries that need to be addressed, need help regarding the same. Mentioning the same below.

1. Is there any library/plugin that can create a Room DB from the Realm DB
2. If the above proves possible, can the data in the previous versions of the app be migrated to the Room DB
3. Has this task been ever tried by any team, is so what were the learnings and pit falls that we might encounter if we decide to go forward with this migration.

PS : The following post talks about the DB migration posted in 2018, checking if there has been any solution since then.
[Android - Migrate data from Realm to Room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911486/android-migrate-data-from-realm-to-room)

Comment: This question will likely be closed as it really goes outside the bounds of what kinds of questions to ask. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that 1) Questions should not seek recommendations for software libraries, tutorials, tools, books, or other off-site resources 2) This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only and 3) Avoid asking questions that would require extended discussion. And this would require very extended discussion. Please post *coding* related questions!